# HTML5 JQuery Mobile - iOS shaking mandatory fields

Tags: javascript, ios, html, jquery-mobile, user-interface

I have a few fields on a screen that the user needs to key in. How I do I shake those mandatory fields when the user does not enter a value?

I am using JQuery Mobile for iOS hybrid app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user submits the form you can check for the mandatory fields and use the JQuery shake animation to shake them.

```
// this event is fired when form is submitted
$("#form_id").submit(function () {

    var name = $("#form_id #name_input").val();

    if (!(name)) {
        $("#form_id #name_input").effect("shake", { times:3 }, 300);
    } else {
        // form input is valid, do whatever you want
    }

    // you might need to return false to prevent default submit actions
    return false;
}
```

Jquery docs: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Shake

Comment: thanks . Will it still work without Form? I am not using forms.

Comment: can you please post your code? What action is being taken once the input fields are filled in?

Comment: currently i am simply checking fields values and then showing a dialog box. that's I am thinking to replace with shaking effect in place of dialog box. Thanks

Comment: okay, then just use this code in the same place where you are doing the "checking"